# Transparent border is leaving small white crescents on border radius

Tags: html, css

I am using the code below for a footer on a page. The problem with it is that, as you will be able if you run the code snippet, there are small white crescents on the bottom corners of the border.

The problem described above is being caused by the line `background-clip: padding-box;`. I cannot remove this line since it is required to create a transparent border.

```css
footer.mycontainer.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(143, 90, 5, 0.88);
  border: 1.5mm;
  border-color: rgba(143, 90, 5, 0.88);
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-style: none;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4mm;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4mm;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4mm;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.ftext.bottom {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.mycontainer {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="mycontainer bottom">
  <p class="ftext bottom">
    Footer text from PHP
  </p>
</footer>
```

In order to rectify the problem I tried replacing the line with code such as `background-clip: content-box;` and `background-clip: border-box;`. These attempts did not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What I did

1. Remove the `background-clip` to get rid of the cresent
2. Set `border: 0` so there's a 0px width border and nothing shows for it

### The code

```css
footer.mycontainer.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(143, 90, 5, 0.88);
  border: 0;
  border-color: rgba(143, 90, 5, 0.88);
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-style: none;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4mm;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4mm;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4mm;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4mm;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4mm;

}
.ftext.bottom {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.mycontainer {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="mycontainer bottom">
  <p class="ftext bottom">
    Footer text from PHP
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what you did?

Comment: This saves me a lot of trouble. Thank you

Comment: You can remove the -webkit and -moz prefixes, they are useless nowadays

Comment: @AnthonyAstige Do you know if there is a way to achieve this without setting `border: 0` so as to allow for borders of a different colour to the main body?

Comment: @vals or do you know how to do this?